# NetSuite Invoice Amount Paid and Amount Due

Tags: forms, netsuite

I am customizing an invoice template for the "Advanced PDF/HTML Templates " templates, I found the field names for Amount Due "amountremaining" and Amount Paid "amount paid" but they show as empty in the invoice. if I go to the "Custom Transaction Form" for the invoice. It shows the "amount paid" and the "amount due" fields, both are checked in the "Show" column, "display type" column shows one as "Normal" and one as "disabled", I can't seem to change the state of the display type. I am at a loss as to what to check so that these values are available in the "Advanced PDF/HTML Templates " for invoices. Any help would be great, thanks

Comment: Both work fine for me: `${record.amountpaid}`, `${record.amountremaining}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just checked one of my PDF template files and those work fine for me.  below is the snippet that I have.  Can you include your code, so that it can be reviewed for issues?

```
    <td colspan="2">
      <table id="balances">
        <tr>
          <th>Subtotal</th>
          <td>${record.subtotal}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>Tax Total</th>
          <td>${record.taxtotal}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>Invoice total</th>
          <td>${record.total}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>Amount Paid</th>
          <td>${record.amountpaid}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>Amount Due</th>
          <td>${record.amountremaining}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>Currency</th>
          <td>${record.currency}</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
```

Comment: I am not sure then as I checked these values and they come back blank, thanks I will have to try something else